# Understanding 'newtype' keyword

Tags: haskell, newtype

For a uni assignment, we have been given a line of Haskell code which shows:

```
newtype TC a = TC ([Id] -> Either TypeError ([Id], a))
```

Firstly, `TypeError` is something which needs to be implemented by us for the assignment so I can't post the data declaration here, but my question is this. How do I read the code above? What is the `a` right after the `newtype TC`? I also don't understand how `TC` is being reused to the right of the equals sign.

I think `a` here is a type variable since `newtype` works similarly to data. I don't know how knowing this will help my understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the `a` right after the `newtype TC`?

The `a` in the newtype declaration

```
newtype TC a = ...
```

expresses much the same as the `x` in a function declaration

```
f x = ...
```

`a` is a type parameter. So you'll be able to use `TC` as, for example, `TC Int` or `TC Bool`, similar to how you're able to use `f` like `f 1` or `f "bla bla"` (depending on its type).

The case `TC Int` is equivalent to the following alternative:

```
newtype TCInt = TCInt ([Id] -> Either TypeError ([Id], Int))
```

> I also don't understand how `TC` is being reused to the right of the equals sign.

That is a bit of a confusing quirk in Haskell. Actually `TC` is *not* reused, rather you're declaring *two separate* entities which are both called `TC`. You could also call them differently:

```
newtype TC_T a = TC_V ([Id] -> Either TypeError ([Id], a))
```

- `TC_T` is a *type constructor*. This is the thing that will appear in type signatures, i.e. `TC_T Int` or `TC_T Bool`.
- `TC_V` is a *value constructor*. You use this when, well, generating values of type `TC_T Int` or `TC_T Bool`.

So for example, you might write these:

```
tci :: TC_T Int
tci = TC_V (\ids -> Right (ids, 37))

tcb :: TC_T Bool
tcb = TC_V (\ids -> Right (reverse ids, False))
```

With your original version it looks like this:

```
tci :: TC Int
tci = TC (\ids -> Right (ids, 37))

tcb :: TC Bool
tcb = TC (\ids -> Right (reverse ids, False))
```

...but it's still two separate things both called `TV` here. Most newtypes in Haskell call the type- and value constructors the same, but often only the type constructor is exported from a module and the value constructor left as an implementation detail.

Most of this is the same for `data` as for `newtype`. You could as well have

```
data TC a = TC ([Id] -> Either TypeError ([Id], a))
```

... the only difference to the newtype version is a subtle indirection: if it's `data`, then the compiler inserts an indirection which allows a bit more lazyness, but in this case there's hardly a point to doing that.

In practice, you generally use `data` only when you need *multiple* constructors and/or a constructor with multiple fields, which `newtype` does not support.

Comment: The difference between type and value constructors is more understandable when there is more than one of them: e.g. `data Tree = Leaf | Branch Tree Tree`

Comment: Thank you, this is a very detailed answer. I will have to let it sit for a while but I can already understand the difference between the TC's and the fact that "a" is a type paramater. Follow up question, can the "a" be a tuple then?

Comment: @mraya99 `a` can be any arbitrary type: `TC (Int, String)`, `TC [Bool]`, `TC (Maybe Bool`, `TC (Bool -> [(Int, String)])` are all valid. Note that in `TC (Int, String)` we are not passing a pair-of-types (i.e., two type arguments), but we are applying `TC` to the type of the tuples (AKA product type) which is written `(Int, String)` in Haskell. So, to be pedantic, `a` can not be a tuple-of-types, but it can be the (single) type of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of *newtype* over *data* is that you can derive via the type that underlies it:

```hs
{-# Language DerivingVia              #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}

import Control.Applicative   (Alternative)
import Control.Monad         (MonadPlus)
import Control.Monad.Except  (ExceptT(..), Except)
import Control.Monad.Fix     (MonadFix)
import Control.Monad.State   (StateT(..), MonadState)
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity(..))
import Data.Kind             (Type)

type    TC :: Type -> Type
newtype TC a = MkTC ([Id] -> Either TypeError (a, [Id]))
  deriving
    ( Functor, Applicative, Alterantive
    , Monad, MonadPlus, MonadState [Id], MonadFix
    )
  via StateT [Id] (Except TypeError)

-- Alternative and MonadPlus rely on these
instance Semigroup TypeError ..
instance Monoid    TypeError ..
```

I had to swap the tuple but this works because of three *newtype*s: `TC a`, [`StateT s m a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT) and [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:ExceptT). The compiler generates an instance for each *newtype* witnessing that it has the same runtime representation as the underlying type.

This is called *representational equality* and is witnessed by [`Coercible`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#t:Coercible).

```
-- instance Coercible (StateT s m a) (s -> m (a, s))
type    StateT :: Type -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
newtype StateT s m a = MkStateT (s -> m (a, s))

-- instance Coercible (ExceptT e m a) (m (Either e a))
type    ExceptT :: Type -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
newtype ExceptT e m a = MkExceptT (m (Either e a))
```

This entails that `TC a` is coercible to `StateT [Id] (Except TypeError) a` and thus we can use `coerce`-based deriving strategies to carry instances between them (like [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/newtype_deriving.html) or [`DerivingVia`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html)).

```
  TC a
={Coercible}
  [Id] -> Either TypeError (a, [Id])
={Coercible}
  [Id] -> ExceptT TypeError Identity (a, [Id])
={Except e = ExceptT e Identity} 
  [Id] -> Except TypeError (a, [Id])
={Coercible}
  StateT [Id] (Except TypeError) a
```

`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` only works on *newtype*s but this does not mean that `DerivingVia` only works on *newtype*s. You can dervive many instances for *data*, for example by `Applicative` lifting methods over `TC` ([`Ap TC a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap)).

Making it a *newtype* does simplify things, the `Applicative` can be derived through the state transformer so we don't need to write any instance by hand.

```hs
data TC a = MkTC ..
  ..

  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid, Num, Bounded)
  via Ap TC a
```

---

The `TC` name serves two purposes in your code ('punning'). I separate them into two different names, for `TC` and the transformers.

The left-hand side is the type constructor:

```hs
>> :k TC
TC :: Type -> Type
>> :k StateT
StateT :: Type -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
>> :k ExceptT
ExceptT :: Type -> (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)
```

and the right-hand side is the value constructor, which I added a `Mk` for disambiguation:

```hs
>> :t MkTC
MkTC :: ([Id] -> Either TypeError (a, [Id])) -> TC a
>> :t MkStateT
MkStateT :: (s -> m (a, s)) -> StateT s m a
>> :t MkExceptT
MkExceptT :: m (Either e a) -> ExceptT e m a
```

The `a :: Type` is an argument to the type constructor:

```hs
TC   :: Type -> Type
TC a :: Type
```

Without a type argument none of those instaces would kind-check because all of those instances require an "unary type constructor" (`Type -> Type`) as an argument. That is to say, a type parameterised by a type:

```hs
Functor         :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
Applicative     :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
Alternative     :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
Monad           :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
MonadPlus       :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
MonadState [Id] :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
MonadFix        :: (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
```